# In JavaScript trying to create dictionary from 3 array objects - Challenge Question

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create dictionary with 3 different arrays

```
myItems = ["Salt", "Pepper", "Oil", "Salt", "Pepper", "Oil", "Onion"]
myQuantities = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
myUnits =  ["gms", "gms", "kgs", "gms", "pound", "kgs", "pound"]
```

Also from above example I want remove the duplicate of "Items", if "Units" are same; ie Salt repeating twice (1 gms and 2 gms), it should be { Salt: '3 gms'}

If units are different then it should be repated twice, ie Pepper repeating twice with different units( 1 gms and 2 pound), it should be {Pepper: '1 gms', Pepper: '2 pound'}

Example code

```
myItems = ["Salt", "Pepper", "Oil", "Salt", "Pepper", "Oil", "Onion"]
myQuantities = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
myUnits =  ["gms", "gms", "kgs", "gms", "pound", "kgs", "pound"]

console.log(myItems);
console.log(myQuantities);
console.log(myUnits);
let final = Object.fromEntries(
    myItems.map((_, i) => [myItems[i], myQuantities[i].toString()+" "+myUnits[i]])
      );
console.log(final)
```

```
Current Result  = { Salt: '2 gms', Pepper: '2 pound', Oil: '2 kgs', Tes: '2 pound' }

Expected Result = { Salt: '3 gms', Pepper: '1 gms', Pepper: '2 pound', Oil: '3 kgs', Tes: '2 Onion' }
```

Comment: Generally, it's a good idea, to have at least one sentence that ends or should end with a question mark, inside of a question.

Comment: Thanks, Trying to edit, but its not allowing

Comment: Expected result is impossible.

Comment: Should use something else to get this result instead of Object.fromEntries ? any suggestion ?

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in an object. Maybe you should make the value of each property an array.

Comment: Then I should convert the unit to common unit, and create dict

Comment: What is `Tes: '2 Onion` in the desired output? Shouldn't that be `Onion: '2 pound'`?

Comment: Thats true, @Barmar

Comment: Are you going to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have duplicate keys in an object. Put the values in an array.

```js
const myItems = ["Salt", "Pepper", "Oil", "Salt", "Pepper", "Oil", "Onion"]
const myQuantities = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
const myUnits = ["gms", "gms", "kgs", "gms", "pound", "kgs", "pound"]

let final = {}
myItems.forEach((item, i) => {
  if (!final[item]) {
    final[item] = [];
  }
  final[item].push(myQuantities[i] + " " + myUnits[i]);
});
console.log(final)
```

Comment: This will not help, this will two value for a key, best option is for duplicate I need to covert unit to common unit  and create dictionary

Comment: This is kind of not straight, achieved with too much if and else

Comment: What if there are no common units? Although all your units are weight, in real recipes some units are in volume, some are in quantity.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved something similar but without the duplicate keys (which you can handle by your own)

```
let myItems = ["Salt", "Pepper", "Oil", "Salt", "Pepper", "Oil", "Onion"]
let myQuantities = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
let myUnits =  ["gms", "gms", "kgs", "gms", "pound", "kgs", "pound"]

let x = myItems.reduce((newObj, entry, idx) =>{
if(!newObj[entry]){
  newObj[entry] = [myQuantities[idx], myUnits[idx]];
} else {
if(newObj[entry][1] == myUnits[idx]){
  newObj[entry] = [(newObj[entry][0] + myQuantities[idx]), myUnits[idx]];
} else {
  // should convert unit here or handle the case properly
}
}

return newObj;
}, {});

Object.keys(x).forEach(ele => x[ele] = x[ele][0] + ' ' + x[ele][1]);

console.log(x);

//result: {Salt: "3 gms", Pepper: "1 gms", Oil: "3 kgs", Onion: "2 pound"}
```